# Will my 2002 Mustang make it from California to Iowa?

Tags: engine, ford, tires, transmission, coolant

I have a great 2002 Mustang automatic 6cyl in great condition, but I am a worrier and want some outside opinions.

I am the second owner of the vehicle. Have owned it for 1year, 7 months and I get my fluids checked regularly, tire pressure, oil change and top offs done every 3-5k, closer to the 5k mark because I don't do that much driving. New tires were purchased by the previous owner shortly before the sale and I have the paperwork, can't remember the date. I replaced the alternator when first purchased.

My work commute is 26 miles roundtrip, 70-75pmh and around town driving. So far I've had no problems. What should I definitely have a look at before deciding to drive it halfway across the country?

Comment: Have you asked a chev owner this question?

Comment: Thank you all for responding! I will probably drive it an give it lots of TLC on the way!

Answer (score 8):

Any car in good operating condition should be able to make the trip.  My advice would be to:

1) Fix any known problems with the car.  This includes making sure the spare tire is in good shape and fully inflated.

2) If your car consumes oil between changes, bring along a spare quart or two.  A long road trip can cause an apparent increase in consumption as the oil will be hotter (and thinner) than usual for longer than usual.

3) Plan ahead for if a breakdown should occur.  One of the most likely causes of a breakdown is a flat tire due to running over debris in the road.  Or a cracked windshield, or any number of other things that just happen regardless of the condition of the car.  Simply having a charged cell phone and someone to call (even if it's AAA) can be enough of a plan.

Also, on a long trip, you can usually expect to end up in one exceptionally long traffic jam.  For me, this happens right about the time I've just finished a cup of coffee and can't wait to get to the next rest area.

Answer (score 7):

If your normal journeys get the car up to temperature and you have trusted it so far, then a long journey should make no difference, in fact cruising speeds should be easier on the car than constant stopping and starting.

If you currently don't loose any fluids and there are are no strange noises, then I wouldn't worry.  But if you really need confirmation, then you need someone who knows what they are looking at to check it over.

It isn't a good idea to change the oil etc just before a long journey, just in case something accidentally does not get tightened up properly and it works loose on your journey.

After saying all this, don't hold me responsible if you have problems :)
Have a good journey.

Answer (score 5):

Take it to a mechanic and have him/her do a bumper to bumper check. The mechanic will let you know if there is anything urgent. You can then choose to risk it or fix it. Good luck on your trip!

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the others.  Every time you stop to gas up or take a break, take a look around the car, check the fluids.

Bring a decent set of tools in case something happens - sockets, breaker bar, screwdrivers, duct tape, zip ties, WD-40, flash light.  Make sure your jack and spare are good and functioning.